# sending request to flask sever using Alamo fire in Xcode error code: -1004

Tags: ios, swift, flask, alamofire

I'm programming in `Swift`. 
In my program i send a get request from the app to a `Python` server i created using `Flask` library, this request is created using `Alamofire` pods incorporated in my project.
When I run the project on the Mac simulator everything is fine but when i am trying to run it on my iPhone I get an error when it tries to send the request:

> cyberProjectFinal[11583:4962447] Task .<3> finished with error - code: -1004

here is my code:

```
private func sendRequestToFlaskServer(url: String, uid: String, name: String, downloadLinks: String, type: String, completion :@escaping (String)->()){  // HTTP Request Using AlamoFire module
    Alamofire.request("\(url)user=\(uid)&name=\(name)&type=\(type)&links=\(downloadLinks)",method: .get).responseData { response in
        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            completion(utf8Text)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Error code ranging from -1009 to -1001 refers to the loss of data packets in request. Try checking your internet connection.

Comment: the internet connection is fine, I have tried to send the request several times when the internet connection was strong and still the error remained the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems an issue with flask... if you solve it let us know!